# Explaining the non-application of the multiplication law of logarithms, when logs are in the denominators.

Tags: logarithms, fractions

I have an A' Levels student who had to solve the following problem:

$ log_2 x + log_4 x = 2$

This was to be solved using the Change of base rule, and then substitution, as follows:

$ \frac{1}{log_x 2} + \frac{1}{log_x 4} = 2$

=>

$ \frac{1}{log_x 2} + \frac{1}{log_x 2^2} = 2$

=>

$ \frac{1}{log_x 2} + \frac{1}{2 log_x 2} = 2$

=>

$ \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{2y} = 2$

and so on.

My student has this confusion:

Given that $log_x 2 + log_x 4 = log_x 8$ why can't we go from

$ \frac{1}{log_x 2} + \frac{1}{log_x 4} = 2$

directly to:

$ \frac{1}{log_x 8} = 2$

I'm having a hard time explaining why... I thought of trying to explain the issue using laws of fraction arithmetic, is that right? What is the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an example. Is it true that
$$\frac12+\frac12=\frac1{2+2}=\frac14\mathrm{?}$$